# Does creating a unique constraint on a column automatically create index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Consider this unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Posts
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Posts_Name
UNIQUE (Name);
```

Does it automatically create index on `Name` column?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

yes it does. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: Worth adding that it's a non-clustered index (as explained in the link).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just to add.. creating primary key automatically creates clustered index.

**EDIT:**
I was wrong... after Lieven's comment:

> When you create a PRIMARY KEY constraint, a unique clustered index on the column or columns is automatically created if a clustered index on the table does not already exist and you do not specify a unique nonclustered index. The primary key column cannot allow NULL values.

Comment: Creating a primary key does **not** automatically creates a clustered index.

Comment: you are right - When you create a PRIMARY KEY constraint, a unique clustered index on the column or columns is automatically created if a clustered index on the table does not already exist and you do not specify a unique nonclustered index. The primary key column cannot allow NULL values.

Comment: I wouldn't say you were "wrong", just that the answer should have been more nuanced. Maybe replace the word "automatically" with "by default", as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434535/3002584).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate index on it as well. this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(SQL.80).aspx describes the differences very well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. A unique constraint creates a unique index.