# Is a primary key automatically an index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, primary-key, constraints

If I run Profiler, then it suggests a lot of indexes like this one

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Users_c_9_292912115__K1] ON [dbo].[Users] 
(
 [UserId] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

UserId is the primary key of the table Users. Is this index better than the one already in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every table needs a clustered index and a primary key. By default, the PK is clustered but it can be non-clustered if you want like you're done.

You have specified a non-clustered PK so the profiler suggests a clustered index...

Note: a table without a clustered index is called a "heap" because it's a pile of unstructured data...

Comment: The data in an un-indexed table is most certainly structured

Comment: "Every table needs a clustered index"
"Note: a table without a clustered index...."
You've contradicted yourself there - what did you mean?

And as for every table needing a primary key - in my experience, SQL Server will allow you to create a table without one, as will most DBMSs.

Comment: Tables do not need to have a clustered index. This is why the concept of a heap exists. Search for the word "heap" in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 39):

Yes a primary key is always an index.

If you don't have any other clustered index on the table, then it's easy: a clustered index makes a table faster, for every operation. YES! It does. See Kim Tripp's excellent [The Clustered Index Debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) for background info.

So really, every useful table (except for maybe staging tables for bulkload or another few rare cases) ought to have a clustered index. If you don't have one, it's quite obvious the DTA would recommend one, and put it on the Primary Key column(s) by default.

Comment: "...makes a table faster, for every operation" other than insert? Doesn't insert have more work to do, as it has to update the index as well?

Comment: NO!! Read Kim Tripp's blog post - quoting: "Inserts **are faster in a clustered table** (but only in the "right" clustered table) than compared to a heap. The primary problem here is that lookups in the IAM/PFS to determine the insert location in a heap are slower than in a clustered table (where insert location is known, defined by the clustered key). "

Answer (score 2):

It is essentially suggesting that you should make the primary key a clustered index rather than an unclustered one. In most cases, this would be a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is better because it is clustered.

Comment: it is clustered by default, but doesn't have to be

Comment: PK from the post is explicitly nonclustered.